# How to use a cursor pagination in sql alchemy

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pagination, database-cursor

I have a postgres database and trying to build an API with SqlAlchemy and I'm wondering how to implement a cursor pagination.

I looked at other examples [here](https://github.com/wizeline/sqlalchemy-pagination/blob/636f872d75e5c5346f903910b7c02430c47c9be0/sqlalchemy_pagination/__init__.py#L28) and also the [flask-sqlAlchemy](https://github.com/pallets/flask-sqlalchemy/blob/818c947b665206fe8edd8c1680b18ce83d3e4744/src/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py#L542) package, but both seem to use a combination of offset and limit. I'm looking for something more performant, similar to what [django rest-framework](https://cra.mr/2011/03/08/building-cursors-for-the-disqus-api/) is using. I can't seem to find anything like that in the documentation. I did find a third party package that seems to handle that [here](https://github.com/djrobstep/sqlakeyset).

I was wondering if there is no built in way to handle cursor pagination?

Comment: Flask-SqlAlchemy does have support for [pagination](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/api/#flask_sqlalchemy.BaseQuery.paginate)

Comment: true but if I look at the [code](https://github.com/pallets/flask-sqlalchemy/blob/818c947b665206fe8edd8c1680b18ce83d3e4744/src/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py#L542), it seems to be just a combination of offset and limit, no?

Comment: ah yes my bad. I did not read the implementation.

Comment: Are you targetting a particular RDBMS?